# ArithmeticException with cosmosdb exclusively with Windows Server 2016

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an API that queries a cosmos db via Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.11.5

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, feedOptions)
                  .Where((s => s != null && s.Type == typeof(foo).Name));
    
IDocumentQuery<T> documents = query.AsDocumentQuery();
    
while (documents.HasMoreResults)
{
  FeedResponse<T> page = await documents.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(); <----- exception
  // More code...
}
```

The ArithmeticException is thrown on the shown line above.  The puzzling part is that this exception is only thrown when the API is hosted in Service Fabric cluster on Microsoft Server 2016 (build 14393).  If I run the solution locally, or in host it in a local cluster in a windows 10 environment (build 10.0.18363.1016) the code runs as expected.

Is there a reason why the Microsoft Server 2016 would cause this exception?

EDIT - Added the actual exception.  Names changed to protect the innocent.

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "code":"-1","message":"[An unexpected exception has occurred.][Message: , Windows/10.0.14393 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.11.5][Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.]",
        "target":"https:<cluster>",
        "innerError":
        {
            "trace":"BadRequestException Message: , Windows/10.0.14393 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.11.5\r\n   
                at <inner-service>.<foo>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n
                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
                at <outer-service>.<foo>d__12.MoveNext() in C:<outer-service-file>:line 208\r\n
                InnerException: \r\n    
                    ArithmeticException Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.\r\n
                    \r\n
                    "
        }
    }
}
```

The final inner exception is thrown at `documents.ExecuteNextAsync<T>()`

Comment: What is the content of the exception?

Comment: I've included the exception in the edit.